# In Kohana query builder is it possible to compare column to another column, rather then a string or other value?

Tags: mysql, kohana-3.2

I am trying to build a query in Kohana and struggling to convert the query given to me by a DB admin into kohana query builder syntax. The query is failing when trying to compare the following:

```
AND du.user_key = dd.user_key
```

Using the syntax

```
->and_where('du.user_key', '=', 'dd.user_key')
```

I know this is because the builder is expecting the params, column, op, value. SO my question is there away to get the builder to recognise the value as a DB column, i have been looking through the docs but but to no avail... Any help would be appreciated.

CHeers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DB::expression

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#database-expressions

So in the case of this example:

```
->where('du.user_key', '=' ,DB::expr('dd.user_key'))
```